# Logging by Chromium/Chrome media modules do not appear in debug log

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'm trying to debug an audio playback delay of 30 seconds in Chrome/Chromium on a WAV file served in real-time for a live conversation. 
I've enabled logging like this on the Chromium command line:
`--enable-logging --v=9 --vmodule=ffmpeg*=9`

Verbose logging from other modules apear in the chromium debug log, but never logging from any of the audio/media modules like ffmpeg, pipeline_controller.

I'm already looking at the events reported in the Experimental Media tab in Developer tools, but need to go deeper.

As I understand the source code the DVLOG statements should cause logging to the debug log.

Any guidance appreciated.

Comment: Do you see it when the value of `--v=1`?

Comment: @Asesh No, I started out with just `--enable-logging --v=1`, which logged nothing from the media modules (but did show verbose content from other modules, e.g. `[2152:11188:0310/082333.143:VERBOSE1:network_delegate.cc(32)] NetworkDelegate::NotifyBeforeURLRequest: https:// ...`.

Answer (score 0):

The media logs are available from two places:

- Chromium [media docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/media/README.md) mention that they're are available by going to: *chrome://media-internals* - All media sessions are listed under the Player tab - Click on one to view Player Properties and **Logs**.
- They're available (see [devtools docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/media-panel/)) per browser tab via the devtools->media tab (you may need choose it via devtools Customize menu (3 dots/mini-burger) under 'More Tools') and clicking on the relevant media session in the Players column and the logs are listed under the Messages tab - Select Log level to see 'All' or specific logs.